# Cannot read property 'hue' of undefined

Tags: javascript, dom-events, paperjs

I am learning how to make animations in JavaScript. I am using `paper.js`, what I am trying to do is generating circles with some effects when a key is clicked. Before that I was just simply trying to change the color of the circles using `onFrame` function that I found from the documentation.But it keeps giving me the error:

> Cannot read property 'hue' of undefined

How can I solve it?

```
<script  type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas">
            
            function onKeyDown(event) {
                var maxPoint = new Point(view.size.width,view.size.height);
                var randomPoint = new Point.random();
                var point = maxPoint * randomPoint;
                new Path.Circle(point, 20).fillColor = 'purple';
            }
            var animatedCircle = new Path.Circle(100,100, 100).fillColor = 'Red';
            function onFrame(event) {
                animatedCircle.fillColor.hue += 1;
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: you're trying to assign animatedCircle and it's fillColor on the same line

Comment: Also, from looking at the Paper.js docs, there is no constructor for Circle that takes three arguments. There's one that takes 2 arguments, one being a point object defining the center, and the other being a number representing the radius. So the circles should be constructed like so:  `new Path.Circle(new Point(100, 100), 100)`

Comment: Thank you very much, combining the two comments above it worked. But i didnt understand why I have to assign fillColor in different line @Romain Durand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an error in this row:

```
var animatedCircle = new Path.Circle(100,100, 100).fillColor = 'Red';
```

and so `animatedCircle.fillColor` is undefined.

Try this:

```
var animatedCircle = new Path.Circle(100,100, 100);
animatedCircle.fillColor = 'Red';
```

Comment: It doesnt work. but I should fill animatedCirle red not path. I dont have path defined

Comment: why should it be in different line? It worked that way.

Comment: It is doable and valid to create an object and immediately set an attribute, on the same line ; and it works and you can see [in this sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/q1bKS8xNVbJSCs5OLUnOUNJRSs5PAfHLEosUEvMycxNLUlOcM4uSc1IVbBXyUssVAhJLMvQgIhpgfn5mXomGoYWBjoKhqYEmkDQw0NRLy8zJcc7PyS8C6lIPSk1RtwYanVSUmphdAFJfrGQVHVsLAA==).

Comment: @arthur.sw Thank you for your response. yes we can create an object and assign it immediately but it throws an error undefined object when you try to access the circles color. [like this sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/q1bKS8xNVbJSCs5OLUnOUNJRSs5PAfHLEosUEvMycxNLUlOcM4uSc1IVbBXyUssVAhJLMvQgIhpgfn5mXomGoYWBjoKhqYEmkDQw0NRLy8zJcc7PyS8C6lIPSk1Rt47JQzVOLxkkrZdRmqqgbWtoDbQ5qSg1MbsAZFyxklV0bC0A).

Comment: Well, it is not related to the fact that the code lies on one line. If you split it on two lines you will have the same result. In fact, the problem is that you try to access `animatedCircle.color.hue` instead of `animatedCircle.fillColor.hue` (replace `color` with `fillColor`).

Answer (score 1):

```
var animatedCircle = new Path.Circle({
    center: (100,100),
    radius: 100,
    fillColor: 'red'
});

function onFrame(event) {
    animatedCircle.fillColor.hue += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the fillColor to be red, so the last thing that was returned was the *string* 'red.' So the end result is that you're just pushing in 'red' every time. Make a new variable.